# If I select "Location, Rotation & Scale" in the viewport by doubletapping " I ", rotation is not keyed

Tags: animation

Whenever I want to key loc-rot-scal, I'd like to just doubletap I to open the Insert Key Menu and select Location, Rotation & Scale, because it's fastest. However, I've realized that when I do this, the rotation transforms will not be keyed. This problem doesn't occur if I click on Location, Rotation & Scale with the mouse button. But I'd like to be able to just doubletap.
[image]

Comment: To open the _Insert Key_ menu it is not necessary to double-tap the `i` key (as for most tools it is not necessary to double-tap a key with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Double-tapping <kbd>i</kbd> brings up an error here under Windows. However, just single-tapping <kbd>i</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> in the 3D view will add all 3 keyframes. If you look at the popup menu when you press <kbd>i</kbd>, you'll see that (at least in Windows) the <kbd>a</kbd> in the <kbd>Location, Rotation & Scale</kbd> entry of the popup menu has an underscore under it. That applies to most of the other entries on that menu. - <kbd>l</kbd> for <kbd>Location</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> for <kbd>Scale</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> for <kbd>Rotation</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> for <kbd>Location & Rotation</kbd>, etc.

[image]

After further discussion in the comments, that exact menu will only appear if you don't have **any** keyframes on your object. If you do already have a keyframe on the object you'll see that the top entry is now <kbd>Available</kbd> (shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>), the shortcut for <kbd>Location, Rotation & Scale</kbd> has changed to <kbd>t</kbd> and that for <kbd>Location & Scale</kbd> changes from <kbd>t</kbd> to <kbd>i</kbd> as shown below which is why double-tapping <kbd>i</kbd> only keyframed the <kbd>Location & Scale</kbd> as asked in the question!.

[image]

Comment: Double-tapping `i` brings up an error on Windows? I'm on Windows and here is no error. It inserts a keyframe for _Rotation & Scale_, and as you explained in your answer with the underscored letters and as your screenshot shows, `i` has an underscore for _Rotation & Scale_ so that's what it should do (and it does on my PC).

Comment: That's odd! I tried that several times before posting that answer and the 'Available' entry never appeared on that menu so I'm not sure what happened there!  I'll edit my answer with the corrected keypresses.

Comment: Same, here, on Linux, default keymap.

Comment: @RobinBetts & John: Actually, it seems I found a bug or something... don't know if this is intended. When I open the _Insert Key_ menu the first time, `i` has an underscore for _Rotation & Scale_. If the object already has a keyframe and I try again, `i` now has an underscore for _Location & Scale_, but _Rotation & Scale_ has an underscore for `n`. I just realized that the OP had a keyframe for all three transforms on frame 1, only on frame 68 (or so) the one for _Rotation_ is missing.

Comment: Obviously, since _Available_ appears when the object already has keyframes somewhere, the whole _Insert Keyframe Menu_ is a bit different. So this could be an intended behaviour, but can be very confusing to users who use shortcuts.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I agree. I haven't worked out exactly what's going on yet, but I did manage to get a menu with 'Available' as the first item once. Since then, I've only ever managed to get the menu I posted. Ah ok. Just seen your latest comment which makes sense (I think)! :^)

Comment: It makes sense as explanation, but not for the workflow in Blender. I mean, for the first keyframe `a` is for _Location, Rotation & Scale_, so basically you can say `a` as in `all` transforms. And for people who want to make sure they animate everything ("transformable") and don't forget something, this might make sense. And for following keyframes it might make sense to have `a` for _Available_ because if you don't animate everything you don't have to remember which channels you were keyframing. But switching between those in basically the same menu can be very confusing, I think.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Wow! So it does! Still trying to get my head round the behaviour, myself.

Comment: @RobinBetts This has potential for a discussion, but there should be developers present :D The stupid thing is, if I have keyframes for more things than just the transforms, like some value in a material, then _Available_ would be great to set keyframes for the transforms **and** the material. But no, _Available_ ignores the material channels. What a bummer.

Comment: Comments partially [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148532/discussion-on-answer-by-john-eason-if-i-select-location-rotation-scale-in-t)